# How do I add my own options page to the QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I want to add a custom options page to the QtCreator. The project wizard makes it easy to create a general QtCreator plugin. However, how to proceed from there and adding new functionality and new widgets? It is only thinly, if at all documented. The only tutorial on how to write QtCreator plugins that I found, is an old pdf file from VCreate Logic.

http://www.vcreatelogic.com/downloads/files/Writing-Qt-Creator-Plugins.pdf

However, this describes the plugin development for a very early QtCreator version (early version 1). Most of the examples don't compile anymore with a current QtCreator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The QtCreator helps tremendously with creating QtCreator plugins. It has its own
project type for QtCreator plugins.

To create a new options page, a QtCreator plugin project is started. In this example
with the name 'myoptionspage'. The QtCreator then creates a working plugin stub, which
is not an options page, but an example how a new menu entry is added the the QtCreator
menu. Nice, but not asked. To create a new options page the method `myoptionspage::initialize`
has to be changed:

```
bool myoptionspage::initialize(const QStringList &arguments, 
QString *errorString)
{
   Q_UNUSED(arguments)
   Q_UNUSED(errorString)

   addAutoReleasedObject(new MyMoptionsPageWidget);
   return true;
}
```

MyMoptionsPageWidget will be the actual options page. This is
the MyMoptionsPageWidget.h file:

```
#include <coreplugin/dialogs/ioptionspage.h>

class MyMoptionsPageWidget 
: public Core::IOptionsPage
{
   Q_OBJECT

public:

    explicit MyMoptionsPageWidget(QObject *parent = 0);

private:

    QWidget *createPage(QWidget *parent);

    void apply(void);

    void finish();

};
```

The important part is the `#include <coreplugin/dialogs/ioptionspage.h>` and the
`public Core::IOptionsPage` inheritance.

In MyMoptionsPageWidget .cpp file:

```
using namespace myoptionspage;

MyMoptionsPageWidget::MyMoptionsPageWidget(QObject *parent) 
: Core::IOptionsPage(parent)
{
   setId(Core::Id("MyOptionsPageID"));
   setDisplayName(tr("My Plugin"));

   // Create a new category for the options page. Here we create a totally
   // new category. In that case we also provide an icon. If we choose in
   // 'setCategory' an already existing category, the options page is added
   // the chosen category and an additional tab. No icon is set in this case.
   setCategory(Constants::MYOPTIONSPAGE_CATEGORY);
   setDisplayCategory(QLatin1String(
      Constants::MYOPTIONSPAGE_CATEGORY_TR_CATEGORY));
   setCategoryIcon(
      QLatin1String(Constants::MYOPTIONSPAGE_CATEGORY_CATEGORY_ICON));
}

// Demoform is an arbitrary QWidget. For this example I hacked one 
// together with the designer.
QWidget *MyMoptionsPageWidget::createPage(QWidget *parent){
    return new Demoform;
}

void MyOptionsPage::apply(){
    // Implement the apply botton functionality
}

void MyOptionsPage::finish(){
    // Implement the ok button functionality
}
```

The file myoptionspageconstants.h is automatically created by the QtCreator.

```
namespace myoptionspage {
namespace Constants {

const char MYOPTIONSPAGE_CATEGORY[] = "H.My Plugin";
const char MYOPTIONSPAGE_CATEGORY_CATEGORY_ICON[] = ":resources/Icon.png";
const char MYOPTIONSPAGE_CATEGORY_TR_CATEGORY[] = 
    QT_TRANSLATE_NOOP("My Plugin", "My Plugin");

} 
}
```

The result: A custom options page with own icon in its own category:

[image]